# Docker Swarm Networking - no communication to some exposed ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-network

I have following docker-dompose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    ports:
      - target: 53
        published: 53
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 53
        published: 53
        protocol: udp
        mode: host
        #      - target: 80
        #        published: 80
        #        protocol: tcp
        #        mode: host
    environment:
      TZ: 'Europe/Warsaw'
      DNS1: 1.1.1.1
      DNS2: 8.8.8.8
      VIRTUAL_HOST: 'pihole.local'
    volumes:
      - ./etc/pihole/:/etc/pihole
      - ./etc-dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 8.8.8.8
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - public

networks:
  public:
```

**Working solution with docker-compose**

Running this with:

```
docker-compose --file docker-compose-pihole.yml up -d
```

exposes ports 53 tcp/udp on host ip address

```
$ nmap 172.30.0.100 -Pn
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-01-02 10:42 CET
Nmap scan report for 172.30.0.100
Host is up (0.0038s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
53/tcp open  domain
```

and dns resolution is working

```
$ nslookup google.pl 172.30.0.100
Server:     172.30.0.100
Address:    172.30.0.100#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.pl
Address: 172.217.16.3
Name:   google.pl
Address: 2a00:1450:401b:804::2003
```

and I'm able to telnet to port 53

```
$ telnet 172.30.0.100 53
Trying 172.30.0.100...
Connected to 172.30.0.100.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

**NOT Working solution with docker stack deploy**

Running the same docker-compose file with

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose-pihole.yml pihole
```

also exposes 53 port tcp/udp on host IP address

```
$ nmap 172.30.0.100 -Pn                       
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-01-02 10:46 CET
Nmap scan report for 172.30.0.100
Host is up (0.0022s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
53/tcp open  domain
```

however name resolution is not working

```
nslookup google.pl 172.30.0.100
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

telnet to port 53 is closed by remote host

```
$ telnet 172.30.0.100 53
Trying 172.30.0.100...
Connected to 172.30.0.100.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Another strange thing is when port 80 is exposed.
In both cases I can access web UI on port 80 connecting to host IP

I have no idea what's going on and how to fix communication on port 53.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

One ENV was missing for pihole:

```
- DNSMASQ_LISTENING: all
```

Two days to figure this out!